# phpmailer for php variables

Tags: phpmailer, php

I am running phpmailer and very much new to it.
Problem definition: Not able to see php variables data in the received email while html content can seen properly.
Below is some of the code:

```
require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                 // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Message';
$mail->Body    = '<body>
    <div align="center"><p7><strong>HELLO WORLD</strong></p7></div>
    <h9><u>Details</u></h9><br/>
<h9><strong>NAME:</strong> <?php echo "$name";?>  <?php echo "$place";?>
</body>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Not able to see data defined under php.
Also $name and $place is the dynamic data for the every mail.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot put php statements in single quotes. use the following instead:

```
$mail->Body    = '<body>
<div align="center"><p7><strong>HELLO WORLD</strong></p7></div>
<h9><u>Details</u></h9><br/>
<h9><strong>NAME:</strong>' . $name . ' ' . $place . '
</body>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the text between " instead of '.

PHP only replaces variables in double quoted strings.

Also you shouldn't use php code in the strings.

```
$mail->Body = "
    <body>
    <div align=\"center\"><p7><strong>HELLO WORLD</strong></p7></div>
    <h9><u>Details</u></h9><br/>
    <h9><strong>NAME:</strong> $name $place
    </body>
";
```

Answer (score 0):

try instead :

```
$mail->Body    = "<body>
<div align=\"center\"><p7><strong>HELLO WORLD</strong></p7></div>
<h9><u>Details</u></h9><br/>
<h9><strong>NAME:</strong>$name $place
 </body>";
```

You don't have to put php tags in your string since you are already in a php context !

Answer (score 0):

Replace Body with :

```
$mail->Body    = '<body>
    <div align="center"><p7><strong>HELLO WORLD</strong></p7></div>
    <h9><u>Details</u></h9><br/>
<h9><strong>NAME:</strong>'.$name.' '.$place.'</body>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    $message .= "Phone: 0181-4606260.<br>";
$message .="Mobile :09417608422.<br>";  

Send_Mail('abc@example.com','Welcome',$message,$headers);
```

try this...